# multilevel longitutudinal model with missing data and survey weights

Tags: panel-data, multilevel-analysis, missing-data, lme4-nlme, survey-weights

I'm estimating a multilevel longitudinal model in lme4, using publicly available survey data. The data include sampling weights, and there is substantial missing data (over 27%). I understand multiple imputation is inappropriate here, because I don't have information on all domains used to generate the sampling weights.

Specifically, I'm predicting students' growth in math achievement scores from 7th to 12th grade (level 1), using student-level covariates including gender, parents' education level, and amount of encouragement received at home (level 2). Finally, I'm using a cluster-level variable of cohort (grade) size by school (level 3).

According to the user guide for the data, the sum of the relative student weights equals the total sample size. Weights were computed based on 3 levels: regional stratum, school, and sample within school. At each wave of data collection, a weight was computed as the joint probability of a student belonging to a stratum, attending a particular school, and being selected for the sample within that school. These individual probabilities were computed based on the population sizes of the grade cohort in the US, the population size of the grade cohort within each stratum, and the population size of the grade cohort in each school sampled from each stratum.

How would I correctly include the weights, while accounting for missing data? My hunch is to use full information maximum likelihood estimation so that I am using all available information from each case.

Comment: Is the multilevel structure in any way related to the sampling weights?

Comment: Yes, the codebook says weights were computed taking into account the region, grade, school, and class size.

Comment: Please elaborate on your model by editing the question. What do you model and what is the nested structure? What type of sample? How were weights calculated? Be specific.